# files and memory. how they are mapped... Debugging, File system "ls -a" files, and Address space of running programs

Tags: linux, file, memory, process, filesystems

in my /lib/modules where the kernel objects resides. Basically they are `.ko` files, So if I have a device driver or any other program and its basically a file. How does the file address, i.e. of /lib/modules/.../../../xyz.ko on hard drive when not running, when the module or program is not loaded into memory different from when its loaded in memory and running.

for example when i do `ls` then the file programs that I see are they coming from memory if they are running programs. So basically question is how linux file system differentiate between `running` programs and files of programs when they are `not running` when we do `ls a` to see the files in directory.

Comment: `ls` shows you files on disk.  `lsmod` shows you whether a copy of the module is loaded into kernel memory.

Comment: @stark how can I get the address space of process in memory. For debugging purposes?

Comment: @stark If that's the case then why we use the addresses from file in debugging  using probing tools like uprobe etc.